# AngularJS (ng-grid) - Drag row individually

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have an array built thanks to ng-grid, where I can drop files :

```
<div id="myTable" ng-controller="myTable" style="" droppable dropzone drop="handleDrop()">
    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I would like to be able to drag only one row from this array, and drop it in another array on my web-page.

I have tried to put enableRowReordering: true, but it does nothing.
I have also tried to put draggable in the differefnt div above. It works but I can only drag the whole array, and not just a row.

Any idea ?
Thank you !

**EDIT** : gridOptions :

```
$scope.gridOptions = { //options of the grid
    data: 'newResults',
    showGroupPanel: false,
    selectedItems:$scope.selectedRows, // getting information on the selected row
    multiSelect:false,
    showSelectionCheckbox:false,
    enableRowReordering: true, //enable the drag ???
    keepLastSelected: true,

    // Event when click on a row
    afterSelectionChange:function(data){
        if ($scope.selectedRows[0] !== undefined){ 
            console.log("The selected row is  : ")
            console.log($scope.selectedRows[0].riskalias) 
        }
    },

    columnDefs: [{field: 'riskalias', displayName: 'Risk Alias'},
        {displayName: 'Options', cellTemplate: '<input type="button" name="view" ng-click="tableView()" value="View">&nbsp;<input type="button" name="edit" ng-click="tableEdit()" value="Edit">&nbsp;<input  type="button" ng-click="tableDelete(row.entity.name)" name="delete" value="Delete">'}
        ]
};
```

Comment: could you post your $scope.gridOptions?
my first idea was to add $scope.gridOptions.rowTemplate and add a draggable directive to the row ... you missed a word in your description. where did you add draggable?

Comment: yes of course, here are my grid options